# How to restart kubelet on master to change flag options and how to apply that in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kops

Kops created a cluster as well as terraform scripts.

How to restart kubelet and provide new flags for garbage collection(manual approach) and how to apply them to terraform?

Problem occurs when I manually kill the kubelet process on master and it keeps getting restarted immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add desired `kubelet` flags to `/etc/default/kubelet` file
the file looks like this after adding flags:
`KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--max-pods=20 --port=10255 [ExtarFlags]`
restart kubelet service `sudo service kubelet restart`.

Answer (score 4):

You could change the /etc/sysconfig/kubelet file.
In the config, append / change the flags you need. Then restart the kubelet service using 
`$ systemctl restart kubelet`